# Conducting business with foreigners

Tags: isaiah

In Isaiah 2:6 (NASB)

> For You have abandoned Your people, the house of Jacob, Because they are filled with influences from the east, And they are soothsayers like the Philistines. **They also strike bargains with the children of foreigners**.

The way the verse is formulated hints that "striking bargains with the children of foreigners" is a problem. Is that so? If yes, what's the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the parallelism:

```
For You have abandoned Your people, the house of Jacob, 
Because   they are filled with influences from the east, 
    And   they are soothsayers like the Philistines. 
          They also strike bargains with the children of foreigners.
```

In this verse, Isaiah was focusing on the negative foreign influences, particularly the sinful practice of soothsaying, so much so that, God abandoned them because these foreign influences turned them away from God. God wasn't against the Israelites doing business with foreigners.

Solomon had business dealing with foreigners like Hiram, 1 Kings 9:

> 10At the end of twenty years, during which Solomon built these two buildings—the temple of the Lord and the royal palace— 11King Solomon gave twenty towns in Galilee to **Hiram king of Tyre**, because Hiram had supplied him with all the cedar and juniper and gold he wanted.

An economy cannot just stop foreign trades. Trading with foreigners is fine. Just don't let foreign gods replace the LORD.

Comment: How would you answer in light of 2 Corinthians 6:14?

Comment: Same warning: Don't let foreign gods replace the LORD.

Answer (score 2):

**Conducting business with foreigners**

Isaiah 2:6 (NASB)

> For You have abandoned Your people, the house of Jacob, Because they
> are filled with influences from the east, And they are soothsayers
> like the Philistines. They also strike bargains with the children of
> foreigners.

**God commanded the Israelites:**

Leviticus 18:24 NASB

> 24 ‘Do not defile yourselves by any of these things; for by all these
> things the nations which I am driving out from you have become
> defiled.

By Isaiah’s day some 800 hundred years later, the Israelites adopted the abominable practices of the surrounding nations and are "are filled with influences from the east". Rather than putting faith in God and his word, they are practicing “magic like the Philistines.” Far from keeping separate from the nations, the land ‘abounds’ with “the children of foreigners”​, doubtless, foreigners who introduce ungodly practices to God’s people.

**For example, due to economic prosperity, they put their trust in their military strength.(Vs7)**

Isaiah 2:7-10 NASB

> 7 Their land has also been filled with silver and gold  And there is
> no end to their treasures;  Their land has also been filled with
> horses,  And there is no end to their chariots.

**They put their trust in wealth and turn away from God (Vs 8,9)**

> 8 Their land has also been filled with idols;  They worship the work
> of their hands,  That which their fingers have made. 9 So the common
> person has been humbled  And the person of importance has been brought
> low,  but do not forgive them.

**When God comes to execute his judgment no rock will be big enough to protect them.**

> 10 Enter the rocky place and hide in the dust  From the terror of the
> Lord and from the splendor of His majesty.